# Is it possible to get a master page from my parent Virtual directory/ application/

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have a virtual directory inside of my main virtual directory in IIS.

can i reference the parent application and reference its master page? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2):

For all intents and purposes, no it's not possible. ASP.NET will not execute an ASPX/ASCX/MASTER outside of it's AppDomain. I recommend you go down a different route with your solution (compiled into a common dll, for example)

**Edit:** One potential question to ask is whether you need a virtual directory or not. What is it that made you chose to separate them in the first place?

Beyond that, you could *possibly* fake it by writing your own virtual path provider, but that would lead to a world of hurt (with the base classes not being compiled, etc).

I recommend you go for the simplest solution possible.

Answer (score 1):

Much to my surprise this is possible-- if you make a virtual directory which points back to your master page folder in the parent application. E.g.:

- /parentApp - root directory for the parent
- /parentApp/Master - master pages for the parent
- /parentApp/childApp - child application
- /parentApp/childApp/Master - a virtual directory pointing to /parentApp/Master

With this setup, this can work in your child web.config:

```
<pages masterPageFile="~/Master/Default.master">
```

I assume that references to other master pages in the @Page directive will work, but I have not tried it.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think it's possible due to security concerns.